# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, json, apache-cordova, getjson

Eu tenho lido sobre este método json e eu simplesmente não entendo e não sei o que consertar, estou usando outro domínio para pegar o json.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
$(function(){
    var url = "http://website.com/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var title = field.title;
            $(".class").append("<a href='page.html?id=" + id + "&title=" + title +");
        });
    });
});
```

Erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://website.com/json.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Como posso passar isso para outro código, tipo esse:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: form,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
```

Json.php:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include "db.php";
    $data=array();
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `course_details`");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
        $data[]=$row;
    }
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Db.php

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db") or die ("could not connect database");
?>
```

Estou abrindo a index.html pelo chrome mesmo, sem ser pelo localhost, e estou fazendo a chama em outro domínio (website.com/json.php), e está com esse problema.

Um pessoal colocou como duplicada., mas não é duplicada, gostaria de uma solução que na outra não tem, preciso tem uma responda clara.

Comment: Anderson, nessa ai não tem o **append** junto.

Comment: Já tentou adicionar o header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); em http://website.com/json.php ?

Comment: Já tentei sim Julio, já tentei colocar extensão do Chrome também, não deu certo.

Comment: Já entrei em tudo que é site, não acho algo que ajude resolver :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caso você não tenha acesso ao servidor para adicionar os cabeçalhos:

Pode usar uma das extensões para o chrome **(para desenvolvimento)**:

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

[CORS Toggle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh)

Estas extensões desabilitam a segurança do chrome com relação a comunicação de hosts diferentes e sem a definição de autorização no cabeçalho (como feita pela função header() ).

**Resumindo** este erro é corrigido adicionando: **(PHP)**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Ou
seu front-end que consome a API deve estar no mesmo host(IP + porta) da sua API.

Comment: No header não funciona, useu a extensão o erro saiu, mas não apareceu nada, no console apareceu isso: jquery.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "website.com/json.php".
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:4
getJSON @ jquery.js:4
(anonymous) @ index.html:203
j @ jquery.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.js:2
ready @ jquery.js:2
I @ jquery.js:2 se eu trocar e colocar usando o servidor localhost e abrindo o arquivo index.html direito funciona normal, quando é em outro servidor da esses erros, eu tinha usado um servidor com https e funcionou, mais já expirou.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo indica que seja um problema de comunicação com o servidor do seu site. Isso ocorre quando você tenta fazer uma chamada para um servidor que está num domínio diferente da origem da sua requisição. Não sei qual tecnologia você está utilizando no seu site, mas é possível habilitar essa comunicação.

Pesquise sobre como habilitar [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) na tecnologia que você está utilizando no sei site.

Comment: Como posso habilitar essa comunicação?

Comment: Pode fazer isso seguindo esse tutorial: https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: estou usando html porque é phonegap.

Comment: Tenta uma forma diferente de fazer a chamada: 
`$.ajax({
    url: 'http://website.com/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});`

Comment: Já tentei também, sem sucesso.

Comment: O seu ajax está sendo emitido de dentro de um servidor http ou você está rodando direto do arquivo?

Comment: Direto no arquivo, usando o json.php de um servidor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65481/discussion-between-matheus-calixto-and-stefano-sandes).